# VSCode ModuleNotFoundError: No module named <...> in Terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal, modulenotfounderror

When I try to import the MWE below from the Terminal in VSCode, I get

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tqdm'`

**temp.py:**

```
import tqdm

print('hello')
```

Here is my Terminal session:

```
(mainenv) Larrys-MBP-5:Desktop larry$ python3
Python 3.9.7 (v3.9.7:1016ef3790, Aug 30 2021, 16:39:15) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import temp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/larry/Desktop/temp.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tqdm
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tqdm'
```

I'm using a conda environment called `mainenv`. I can confirm (via `conda list`) that `tqdm` is installed:

[image]

I can also confirm that VSCode is using `mainenv` as the interpreter:

[image]

I get the same error if I replace `tqdm` with other packages too, like `jsonpickle` and `tabulate`. But if I replace it with `numpy` or `networkx`, for example, it works fine.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Did You Use Pip Or npm? When I try to use npm in vscode for python modules it doesn't work, it works for me when I use pip though.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I use conda, not pip or npm.

Comment: sorry i dont know how to use conda, but try using pip to see if it works